# Login using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I cannot login to this site.

This is the url.

https://swayam.gov.in/azurelogin?continue=/

What I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://swayam.gov.in/azurelogin?continue=/")
login_google_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GoogleExchange"]')
login_google_btn.click()
```

I need to login with google and hence required to click that button.

Output:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="next"]"}
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.106)
```

Then, I checked to send keys to the username and password fields, but encountered similar error.

What's going wrong?

Comment: After clicking Google button, it redirects to another page which doesnt have the Next button. That is probably why this error shows up.

Comment: Try `...by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button")`

Comment: it needs time to load page - you could use `time.sleep(1)` after `driver.get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it uses JavaScript to load data and you have to wait a little for elements on page.

You can use `time.sleep(1)` or `driver.implicitly_wait(1)` to wait 1 second.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

driver.get("https://swayam.gov.in/azurelogin?continue=/")
#time.sleep(1)

#login_google_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('GoogleExchange')
login_google_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GoogleExchange"]')
login_google_btn.click()
```

See doc [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for other methods.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://swayam.gov.in/azurelogin?continue=/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#login_google_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'GoogleExchange')))
login_google_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GoogleExchange"]')))
login_google_btn.click()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! time.sleep(1) simply holds for 1 second whereas I'm confused with driver.implicitly_wait(1). Please clarify what's going around and the difference between both.

Comment: you have link to `Waits` and there you will get all information.

Comment: `implicitly_wait(1)` will wait 1 second after `get()` load page before it gets DOM with HTML and run next code in your script. `time.sleep()` is simple method to wait but selenium has `implicitly_wait` for this. Using `wait.until()` you can set longer time and it will check every 0.5s if element is ready